# Why is there an not error on removing 'public' keyword from second class and not replacing it by anything in the same java file if default is public?

Tags: java

I have two classes in a single java file, no internal class or any parent or child class, just two classes in a single file. I know two classes cannot be public in a single java file, they need to be declared in seperate java files. As far as I know is that if we don't specify any access specifier before the class name, the default specifier is given which is public. So if I remove the 'public' keyword from the second class which is not the main class, why does the error of not putting the class in a seperate file go away?

```
class A{
    
     int a,b;

     static void doSomething(int a, int b){
        int c;
        c=a+b;
    }
}

public class generateSumEg{
    public static void main(String ags[]){
        
        //call function
    }
```

Comment: *"the default specifier is given which is public"* ... no, the default modifier is not public for classes.

Comment: `public class X` means everyone can see `X`. `class Y` means only the package in which it was declared can see `Y`. See [What is the difference between public, protected, package-private and private in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/215497/9997212).

Comment: For your last question, a source file can contain 1 (unnested) public class and multiple (unnested) package-private classes.  It cannot contain multiple public classes.  (But your earlier assumption about the default modifier are incorrect which is the main cause of your confusion.)

Comment: *"As far as I know is that if we don't specify any access specifier before the class name, the default specifier is given which is public."* 
 You are incorrect.  The default access is "package private", which has no specific keyword.

Comment: Got it, thanks y'all